# How do you import JAMA in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, package, jama

How do you import JAMA in java? I keep getting errors when I try to import it.

Comment: How are you importing it? What errors are you getting? The more specific you can get about your problem, the more specific we can be with answers.

Comment: I guess you are using  Jama-1.0.2.jar from this link http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/ just include that jar in your classpath and you would be able to use its packages. I hope you are using some IDE like eclipse. In that case go to project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> add external jar. will post my answer let me know its the correct jama we are talking about.

Comment: JAMA is a Java Matrix package

Comment: Yeah, I'm using it from http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/

Comment: This is where I've put the package:
file:///C:/Users/Gab/Pictures/Capture.PNG

These are the errors I'm getting:
file:///C:/Users/Gab/Pictures/Capture1.PNG

I'm using eclipse btw

Comment: I cannot  see the files they are on your local file system. In order to show me place it on internet somewhere and then provide the link

Comment: This is where I've put the package: http://postimg.org/image/5cay4iwfv/

These are the errors I'm getting: http://postimg.org/image/dbn99fwrh/

Comment: that .zip will contain some .jar files keep those jar files there and try again, I am not sure the eclipse support and references java classes from .zip file.

Comment: Got it now, thanks Samwise Gamgee

Comment: will post my answer please accept it

Answer (score 2):

In case if you are using the JAMA library from [JAMA](http://%20math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama)

In this case you need to extract the zip file and place it in the classpath of your project.
If you are using eclipse then in that case goto Project(right click)-> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Library -> Add external jars. and select the jars that you want in the classpath of your project.